# flex php mysql - post multiple rows of data

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex

There are a few examples on the web showing how to post a row/form to mysql with flex php. I think it will be valuable if it allows user to post multiple rows of data. Supposed I have a datagrid and its id is myDG, how can I post the datagrid data to a table in mysql? I am using Flash Builder 4 and I need a solution based on Flex 3/4 + PHP + MySQL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be done this way:

1. Create a `ValueObject` class with several params, some used in the data grid and some not.
2. Insert dynamically using `DataGrid.dataProvider.addItem(myValueObject);`
3. Create a PHP function with 2 params, $number_of_rows (in flex is `DataGrid.dataProviderLength`), and the other param is `$item`, with is the `DataGrid.dataProvider.`
4. The INSERT function might be something like this:

   `INSERT INTO table (producto, id, precio, stock) 
   VALUES ("$producto", "$id", "$precio", "$stock") 
   , ("$producto2", "$id2", "$precio2", "$stock2") 
   //this must be repeated the number of rows
   , ("$productoN", "$idN", "$precioN", "$stockN"); 
   //Several times`
5. Sometimes after placing the call in flex the data is not inserted, so you need something like this `myphpService.commit();`

I will try to make a full example later.
Thank you.